# How do Ethereum clients cope with future blocks?

Tags: blockchain, yellow-paper

According to [*the Yellow Paper*](http://yellowpaper.io/), the restrictions on block timestamps, H<sub>s</sub>, are,

- H<sub>s</sub> ∈ ℙ<sub>256</sub> (Mathematical term #35) ― ①,
- and H<sub>s</sub> > P(H)<sub>H<sub>s</sub></sub> (Mathematical term #48 and #56) ― ②,

where P(H)<sub>H<sub>s</sub></sub> is the parent (previous) block's timestamp, and ℙ<sub>256</sub> is a set of natural numbers less than 2<sup>256</sup>.

It seems [*the Yellow Paper*](http://yellowpaper.io/) allows *future blocks* (blocks that have a future timestamp) ― ③, as there's no restriction apart from ① and ②.

But how do *Ethereum* clients actually cope with them? Do they really accept any *future blocks* as [*the Yellow Paper*](http://yellowpaper.io/) allows?

I took a quick glance at the source code of *geth* and *cpp-ethereum*, and it seems `ErrFutureBlock` and `"allowFutureBlocks"` are relevant, but I couldn't fully understand what they are doing with them.

If there's something I missed or was wrong above, please let me know.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Pretty math!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I read the source code of *Eth*, *Geth*, *Parity*, *pyethapp*.](https://github.com/wlzla000/understanding-ethereum/blob/master/Ethereum/FutureBlockHandling.md)

- *Eth* keeps *future blocks* (in `m_future` map object) and later processes them at the time specified in the timestamp.
- *Geth* and *Parity* accept *future blocks*, but only maximum 30 seconds future ones. Otherwise, discard. *So clever.*

If they were naïve clients, so implemented the block timestamp validation with only the restrictions on *the Yellow Paper*, they would have integer overflow vulnerabilities may lead to *Denial of Service*.

#### In short

> Do they really accept *any* future blocks as *the Yellow Paper* allows?

No.

Comment: Out of interest, if Geth and Parity get a block with a timestamp 29 seconds in the future, do they update the timestamp of the block they're mining to be later than the one they just accepted, or do they just keep trying to mine a block that, if successful, they would consider invalid because the timestamp goes backwards?

Comment: @EdmundEdgar Good catch. Now I'm reading the source code of Parity and Geth about what you said. I'll comment as my investigation gets done.

Comment: @EdmundEdgar  Done. They update the timestamp of the block they're mining to be 1 second later than the future block they just accepted. _Geth_ waits (sleeps) for some seconds not to mine future blocks, whereas _Parity_ doesn't. :)